# How to build boolean expression from these logic gates

Tags: logic-gates

I have these `xor` logic gates and I want to create a truth table from it. However I am having issue reading it from logic gate. Could anyone show me a minimal example how to convert this to a boolean expression?

[image]

Comment: Name the inputs. Then, going from left to right write the boolean expression on top of each line till you reach the output.

Comment: @EugeneSh. would the second one look like `(A xor B) xor (C xor D)`?

Comment: @squnk Are you supposed to provide answers like that? Or are you supposed to use only AND, OR, and NOT?

Comment: Yes. Also note, that `xor` is associative.

Comment: @jonk I need to conver this into a table

Comment: @squnk Then you need to know how to lay out a table (or k-map.) Your second example has four inputs. Do you know how to lay out a proper k-map table for four input cases?

Comment: @jonk I have a 4 bit binary table but I do not know exactly where should I put `1`. Especially for the first image

Comment: @squnk Don't you have a 2-bit binary table for XOR (or just know how it works, in your head?) If you do, then is your difficulty coming from how to examine and merge two different tables or a table with an input?

Comment: @jonk I have a correct answer for this https://i.imgur.com/bHK60qZ.png but I do not understand how these 1 and 0 at the very right side are filled. I do not know how to read that from the gates. I know xor is when value is only A or B

Comment: @squnk the 1 and the 0 at the end are filled by whether the expression evaluates to true or false when the inputs have the values in that row. You already found the expression needed - "(a xor b) xor (c xor d)". So now go through the truth table and for each of the different input combinations, plug them into the expression and see if it results in true or false.

Comment: @squnk to get you started: for the first row, (0 xor 0) = 0, so (0 xor 0) xor (0 xor 0) simplifies to 0 xor 0, which is 0. So the last column has a zero in the first row

Comment: @InBedded16 Thanks I understand now, but 1 more question, the K-map loks pretty weird, it has no pairs at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You provided a [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFe3Z.png) of your second example and it appears you've now gathered things up. So here's things done explicitly. Hopefully, it helps a little to deepen it.

If you insert some columns for the results of combining **A** and **B** and for combining **C** and **D**, then you get an expanded table which looks like this:

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\overset{\text{2nd Example Solution}}{
\begin{smallmatrix}
\begin{array}{|cc|c|c|cc|c|c}
\hline
A&B&A\oplus B&&C&D&C\oplus D&&F\\
\hline
0&0 &0 && 0&0 &0 && 0\\
0&0 &0 && 0&1 &1 && 1\\
0&0 &0 && 1&0 &1 && 1\\
0&0 &0 && 1&1 &0 && 0\\
0&1 &1 && 0&0 &0 && 1\\
0&1 &1 && 0&1 &1 && 0\\
0&1 &1 && 1&0 &1 && 0\\
0&1 &1 && 1&1 &0 && 1\\
1&0 &1 && 0&0 &0 && 1\\
1&0 &1 && 0&1 &1 && 0\\
1&0 &1 && 1&0 &1 && 0\\
1&0 &1 && 1&1 &0 && 1\\
1&1 &0 && 0&0 &0 && 0\\
1&1 &0 && 0&1 &1 && 1\\
1&1 &0 && 1&0 &1 && 1\\
1&1 &0 && 1&1 &0 && 0
\end{array}
\end{smallmatrix}}
\end{array}
$$

Note that **F** is the result of performing an XOR on the two newly inserted columns.

That's one way to approach it.

The second logic, though, also just generates the parity where '1' occurs when an odd number of inputs are '1' and where '0' occurs when an even number of inputs are '1'. So that would be another way of producing the right output. But you'd need to have been familiar enough with the logic to realize this.

The first logic does the same thing, just differently. So I think you are being asked to discover this symmetry under XOR on your own.

Once you get used to it, you will also see this 4-bit k-map as a familiar pattern:

$$\begin{array}{rl}
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
A\oplus B\oplus C\oplus D&\overline{B}\:\overline{A}&\overline{B}\: A&B \:A&B \:\overline{A}\\
\hline
\overline{D}\:\overline{C}&0&1&0&1\\
\overline{D}\: C&1&0&1&0\\
\vphantom{D\:\overline{C}}D\: C&0&1&0&1\\
D\:\overline{C}&1&0&1&0
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
\end{array}$$